# Exibir ID do usuario na URL em PHP

Tags: php, aplicação-web

Olá, estou tentando fazer com que o ID do usuário seje exibido na url quando ele logar. Fiz uma função que recebe o login e senha do usuário e retorna o ID. Porém quando o usuário se loga, o ID que mostra na URL é sempre '0'. Independente dos usuários que logarem.

index.php

```
    <form method="POST" action="conteudo.php" name="logar">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="LOGIN"/>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="SENHA"/>
            </label><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ACESSAR"/>
            <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="CADASTRAR"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

conteudo.php

```
if($_POST['enviar']){
    $login = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = sha1($_POST['pass']);

    if(verificaUsuario($conexao,$login,$senha)){
        $id = pegandoID($conexao,$login,$senha);
        header("Location: principal.php?id={$id}");PASSANDO ID PARA URL AQUI

    }elseif(!verificaUsuario($conexao,$login,$senha)){
        header("Location:index1.php?erro=#");
    }
}elseif($_POST['cadastrar']){
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
}
```

banco.php

```
include "config/config.php";

try{
    $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host={$servidor};port=3306;dbname={$banco}",$usuario,$senha);
}catch(PDOException $error){
    echo "Erro: " . $error->getMessage() . "<br>";
    die();
}function pegandoID($conexao,$login,$senha){
    $sql = $conexao->exec("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login' AND senha='$senha'");
    return $sql;}
```

Comment: O método [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.exec.php) do PDO não retornará o `id` selecionado; ao invés, use o [`query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php).

Comment: Mudei, mas ai aparece o erro Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\phpoo\Testes\conteudo.php on line 11. A linha 11, é a linha do primeiro header

Comment: Não é somente uma alteração de texto, por isso eu linkei as respectivas documentações. Leia cada uma e entenda como funciona.

Comment: Não consegui resolver o erro. Continua aparecendo o ID 0 na url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim

```
include "config/config.php";

try{
    $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host={$servidor};port=3306;dbname={$banco}",$usuario,$senha);
}catch(PDOException $error){
    echo "Erro: " . $error->getMessage() . "<br>";
    die();
}

function pegandoID($conexao,$login,$senha){
    $sql = $conexao->query("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login' AND senha='$senha'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    /*Aqui retorna um array, e sabemos que será apenas uma linha.
      Então trata ele e retorna so o id que você precisa.*/
    return $sql['id'];
}
```

Sugestão:

->sha1  - Seria melhor você utilizar o [crypt()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.crypt.php), é mais seguro, arriscaria até que não seria possível rolar um decrypt nela.

->config/config.php - Tente não deixar variáveis com config de banco no php, você poderia ter um arquivo referência só para buscar estes valores, como um xml, ou utilizando a lib q o laravel utiliza [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: Fiz a modificação, porém exibe um erro agora. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\phpoo\Testes\banco.php on line 32. A linha 32 é a que contém o select para pegar o ID.

Comment: Roda de novo, faltou o fetch, que acaba retornando direto o result.

Comment: Valeu Luiz, funcinou. Muito obrigado.